# How do you find the amount of free space on a mounted volume using Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, volumes

I am using the following code to determine free space on a volume.
The folder was provided using NSOpenPanel.  The item selected was a mounted volume and the path returned is \Volumes\Name

```
NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemAttributesAtPath:folder];

unsigned long long size = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
```

Is there a better method to determine the free space on a mounted volume using Cocoa?

Update: This is in fact the best way to determine the free space on a volume.  It appeared it wasn't working but that was due to the fact that folder was actually /Volumes rather  than /Volume/VolumeName

Comment: Why the backslashes (\\)? POSIX paths use forward slashes (/).

Comment: I typed that by habit, working more often in the Windows world.  The path is as it was retrieved from NSOpenPanel.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I got on this while googling for same problem. To anyone who wouldn't check provided method with documentation. fileSystemAttributes is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.5. You should use attributesOfFileSystemForPath method

Comment: For those of us who get this answer when looking for a Swift snippet: `let attribs = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: volumeURL.path);
if let sizeValue = attribs[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] {
  print("\((sizeValue as! NSNumber).floatValue)")
}`

Answer (score 3):

The code provided IS the best way in Cocoa to determine the free space on a volume.
Just make sure that the path provided to [NSFileManagerObj fileSystemAttributesAtPath] includes the full path of the volume.  I was deleting the last path component to assure that a folder rather than a file was passed in which resulted in /Volumes being used as the folder which does not give the right results.

```
NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemAttributesAtPath:folder];

unsigned long long size = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

statfs is consistent with results from df. In theory NSFileSystemFreeSize comes from statfs, so your problem should not exist.

You may want to run statfs as below as a replacement for NSFileSystemFreeSize:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int main()
{
    struct statfs buf;

    int retval = statfs("/Volumes/KINGSTON", &buf);

    printf("KINGSTON Retval: %d, fundamental file system block size %ld, total data blocks %d, total in 512 blocks: %ld\n",
            retval, buf.f_bsize, buf.f_blocks, (buf.f_bsize / 512) * buf.f_blocks); 
    printf("Free 512 blocks: %ld\n",  (buf.f_bsize / 512) * buf.f_bfree); 
    exit(0);
}
```